# AWS Lambda layer zip has "nodejs/nodejs" in internal folder path

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-lambda-layers

We code our AWS application in nodejs, and use SAM to build and deploy it.  We have had great success with this, uploading 50+ Lambdas at once, with two layers.

But suddenly our layer zip files have this internal structure, and we of course get `Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module [xyz]` errors

```
[root] +
       |
       nodejs +          <--- why two of these?
              |         
              nodejs +   <--- why two of these?
                     |
                     node_modules +
                                  |
                                  (etc.)
```

We cannot find anything we've changed.

We can see this happening locally when we run `sam build`.
[image]

Any suggestions most welcome!

### Update

Another observation:  This problem occurs when we do `sam build`.  But if we do a `sam deploy ...` without a `build` first it works fine.  So this means we DO have a solid workaround, but it's worrying that something so fundamental is misfiring.

And addressing Matt's thoughts below, we've hunted for any odd config that might insert an errant string "nodejs" -- but found nothing.

Comment: Can you include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the build?

Comment: @Matt, thanks -- and yeah, I was hoping to avoid that.  I know it is the best-practice here, no doubt. But boiling down an entire Vue-based website to a minimum version that still presents the problem, but isn't so warped from the original that it's essentially unrelated...will be a challenge.  I had hoped (and still do!) that someone would recognize the problem on its face.

Comment: It's unlikely to be the vue build, it will be how you are copying or extracting something to the aws build but without some code/config, hard to say.

Comment: or it could be the same thing in the vue build I guess, specifying a `nodejs` somewhere in output config it shouldn't be